# hack for including doi in agsm bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style, doi

Is there a way of including a doi in `agsm` bibliography style? I know I can create my own file using `latex makebst` but I was hoping there was a way of altering the `agsm.bst` file to include doi in the references. Is there a way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could proceed as follows:

- Find the file `agsm.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `agsmdoi.bst`. (Don't edit the file `agsm.bst` directly.)
- Open the file `agsmdoi.bst` in a text editor. The editor you use to edit your `.tex` files will do fine.
- You first need to add a field type named `doi`. To this effect, find the `ENTRY` list (it starts on ca. line 20 of the file). Find the lines

  ```
      chapter
      edition
  ```

  and insert the line

  ```
      doi
  ```

  between these two lines.
- Find the function `write.url`. (It'll should start around line 162.)

  *After* this function, insert the following code in the file to define a new function named `write.doi`:

  ```
  FUNCTION {write.doi}
  { doi empty$
      { "" }
      { new.block "doi: " doi * "" * }
    if$ 
  }
  ```

  If you want to use a prefix other than `doi:`, change the string to whatever suits your needs.
- Next, find the following group of four lines in each of about 14 functions -- starting with `FUNCTION {article}` and ending with `FUNCTION {unpublished}` -- that serve to format and typeset the contents of these entry types:

  ```
    new.block
    note output
    fin.entry
    write.url
  ```

  Assuming that you want the contents of the entry's `doi` field to by typeset after `note` but before `url`, you should insert the line

  ```
    write.doi output
  ```

  between the lines that say `note output` and `fin.entry`; repeat up to 13 times. I suppose that if you know for sure that your bibliography will *never* contain entries of type `mastersthesis` or `phdthesis`, say, you can skip editing the corresponding functions. Likewise, if you know that certain entry types *never* have a `doi` field, you needn't edit the corresponding functions.
- Save the file `agsmdoi.bst` either in the same directory where your main tex file is stored or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Use the modified bibliography style by issuing the command `\bibliographystyle{agsmdoi}`. Run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to propagate all changes.

Here's a self-contained MWE (minimum working example) that uses the `agsmdoi` bibliography style. Note that I don't load the [harvard](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/) package but, instead, both the [natbib](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/) and [har2nat](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/har2nat/) packages; doing so provides full compatibility with the `hyperref` package (if that's needed). Note further the use of the `\url{...}` wrapper around the contents of the `doi` field. Providing this wrapper allows line breaks and provides a mechanism for making the `doi` string clickable if the `hyperref` package is loaded as well. Observe that this treatment is somewhat specific to working with the bibliography styles of the `harvard` package. If you used a style such as `plainnat` you should *not* provide an `\url` wrapper for `doi` fields.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{abcd:2013,
author = "Torben G. Andersen and Tim Bollerslev and Peter F. Christoffersen and Francis X. Diebold",
title = "Chapter 17 --- {Financial Risk Measurement for Financial Risk Management}",
editor = "George M. Constantinides and Milton Harris and Ren{\'e} M. Stulz",
publisher = "Elsevier",
year = "2013",
volume = "2, Part B",
pages = "1127-1220",
series = "Handbook of the Economics of Finance",
issn = "1574-0102",
doi = "\url{http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-44-459406-8.00017-2}",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780444594068000172",
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[margin=1.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{natbib,har2nat,url}
\urlstyle{same}
\bibliographystyle{agsmdoi}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{abcd:2013}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```