# BIBTEX - Help needed for adding ISBN in agsm bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, harvard-style

I am writing a report in a modified report class and am using `agsm` as a bibliography style. Using the help of:

[hack for including doi in agsm bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/194454)

I managed to add a DOI to my modified bibliography style. Now I wanted to do the same trick to add a ISBN to the `book` entry type.

In my modified `.bst` file I added in the *ENTRY* function *isbn* in between *institution* and *journal*. Then I added a function according the instructions of the link above.

```
FUNCTION {write.isbn}
    { isbn empty$
    { "" }
    { new.block "ISBN " isbn * }
    if$
}
```

then finally I modified the `book` entry to the following:

```
    FUNCTION {book}
    { output.bibitem
      list.label.output
      " \harvardyearleft " list.year * "\harvardyearright " * output.nonnull
      author empty$
      { editor "author and editor" item.check }
    { crossref missing$
    { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
    'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  title.field field.used =
    { skip$ }
    { format.btitle "title" output.check }
  if$
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.edition output
      publisher "publisher" output.check
      address output
    }
    { format.book.crossref output.nonnull
      format.edition output
    }
  if$
  new.block
  note output
  write.isbn output
  write.doi output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

Again following the instructions of the link above. However, if I reran LaTeX and BibTeX  (even multiple times), no isbn shows up. Can somebody help? Is there another way to make `agsm` show the ISBN or another 'hack' that may help?

Comment: I followed the steps you described and things worked for me. Note that you don't describe defining `write.doi`, so your `write.doi output` might cause an error. You can find the `agsm-isbn.bst` that I used at https://gist.github.com/moewew/f670f3a8bc511378f4fa322eedfd86a0

Comment: I used your code and then added the DOI again, and it worked. Thank you:)