# Include DOI in the 'agsm' biblio style without altering the agsm.bst file?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, doi

I would like DOI to appear while using the `agsm` bibliography style. One solution suggested is to alter the `.bst` file (see [hack for including doi in agsm bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194454/hack-for-including-doi-in-agsm-bibliography-style)) but working on Overleaf, that is not appropriate.

Another solution would be to use the `plainnat` bibliography style, but then the first name appears before the last name, and to change that, you need to modify the `.bst` file too ([Displaying author's name in a bibliographic entry in the form: Surname, First Initial of Firstname](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/131087/displaying-authors-name-in-a-bibliographic-entry-in-the-form-surname-first-in)).

Is there a way to solve this issue without modifying the `.bst` file? Or is there an easy way to modify it on Overleaf?

Comment: the bath.bst bathx.bst show the doi and you can use it with overleaf - bath is a flexible version of the harvard referencing system - which I use instead of agsm now

Comment: You can also use the 'modified `.bst` file approach' on Overleaf: Usually you can get the `.bst` from CTAN. You could then modify it on your machine and upload the `.bst` file to your Overleaf project, where it will be picked up by BibTeX and can be used as expected.

Comment: ... That said, I understand that this approach is a bit ... clunky. There is, however, generally no alternative to modifying `.bst` files if you want to change the output of a BIbTeX style (some styles are customisable with macros from the document preamble to some degree, but not in a way that adds support for new fields). An alternative would be to work around your style not supporting a `doi` field and using a general-purpose field (as is often done for URLs with the BibTeX base styles), but again, that doesn't feel nice. ...

Comment: ... A third alternative is to find a newer BibTeX style that supports newer fields and the features you want. https://ctan.org/pkg/bath-bst as suggested by fcbsd above would certainly not be a bad choice. Or you could switch from BibTeX to `biblatex` (which is a little more complex than just changing the style), `biblatex` can be configured with TeX code in the preamble of your document, so there is no need to mess with any `.bst` files.

Comment: The switch to bath.bst is great with two minor drawbacks: doi is now shown through the url (from "DOI: XXX.XX.XX" to "Available from:https://doi.org/XXX.XX.XX") and the ISBN do not appear anymore for books. That's fine for the first one, but do you have a solution for the second? 
The two other suggested alternatives are fine but more clunky indeed :)

Comment: And thank you for your replies!

Comment: Now you are running into the same issue with `bath.bst`: The treatment of DOIs and omission of ISBN is coded into the `.bst` file. If you want to change that, you have to modify a copy of the `.bst` file. As mentioned before, generally you should expect having to modify the `.bst` file to change the output of a BibTeX style (there are *some* exceptions for common modifications in *some* styles, but usually not for bigger things like this).

Comment: Understood. Thank you @moewe for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @moewe, the easiest solution would be to use a general-purpose field accepted by agsm. I am working with my university's version of LaTeX and cannot modify or create any of such files. The paper I want to submit to asks for references in Harvard and with DOI.

I have followed [this](https://www.bibtex.com/f/note-field/) suggestion and used the "note" field as follows:

```
@article{acacio_changes_2021,
    title = {Changes in surface water drive the movements of Shoebills},
    note = {doi: 10.1038/s41598-021-95093-5},
    % other information
}
```

Produces:

[image]

The result is good enough for me.